# How to access the names of fields in Django UniqueConstraint?

Tags: django, django-4.0

*Accepted answer for original question. Still not OK for "edit 1" (below)*

---

**Original Question**

I want to access the field names when declared in Meta class :

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = CharField(...)
    author = CharField(...)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                # fields=['name', 'author'],       # solution 1
                Lower("name"), Lower("author"),    # solution 2
                name="unique__book_author",
            ),
        ]
```

With *solution 1*, I access with `Book._meta.constraints[0].fields` => `('name', 'author')`.

With *solution 2*, `Book._meta.constraints[0].fields` is empty :'(

Any idea ?

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/

---

**edit 1**

All fields are not necessarily a *function* like `Lower`. If "author" is not a CharField but FKField, `*expressions` could be :

```py
UniqueConstraint(Lower("name"), "author", name="unique__book_author")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
fileds = []
for expression in Book._meta.constraints[0].expressions:
    fields.append(expression.lhs.name)

print(fileds)
# Output: ['name', 'author']
```

### Update

to get the constraints that are not expressions try this

```
filed_names = Book._meta.constraints[0].columns
```

Comment: Well. I have to say hat it _almost_ works. I just had to remove `target`. Maybe you could edit your answer so I can accept your answer ?

But I'm not entirely satisfyed :)... if one of the expression is not a "function" (like `Lower`), then `lhs` porperty raises `AttributeError: 'F' object has no attribute 'lhs'`

Comment: i have update the answer, if the expression is not an expression then it would appear in Book._meta.constraints[0].fields, so you would have to append results of both _meta.constrains.[0] and _meta.constraints[0].expressions

Comment: Well, with `UniqueConstraint(Lower("name"), "author", name="unique__book_author")`I get `Book._meta.constraints[0].fields == ()` and `Book._meta.constraints[0].expressions == (Lower(F(name)), F(author))`. I miss something ?