# How to access the names of fields in Django UniqueConstraint : 2?

Tags: django, django-4.0

> *I have original question here [How to access the names of fields in Django UniqueConstraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75886549/how-to-access-the-names-of-fields-in-django-uniqueconstraint) but **it do not answer** my question when `*expressions` contains different kind of "fields". I left the accepted answer.*

---

I want to access the **unique** constraint field names when declared in Meta class :

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = CharField(...)
    author = ForeignKey(...)
    description = ...

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                Lower("name"), "author",
                name="unique__book_author",
            ),
        ]

    def do(self):
        unique_fields = ...  # should be ["name", "author"]
```

All fields are not necessarily a *function* like `Lower`. In this case, author is a foreign key.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Idea

1. Get constraints via `model._meta.constraints`
2. Filter only unique constraints
3. For each unique constraint, do the following

   1. If it does not contain expressions, get the field names from `constraint.fields`.
   2. Otherwise, get a field name from each expression by using `expression.deconstruct()` method.

## Solution

```py
from django.db import models


def get_unique_constraint_fields(model):
    unique_constraints = (
        c for c in model._meta.constraints
        if isinstance(c, models.UniqueConstraint)
    )
    fields = []
    for constraint in unique_constraints:
        if not constraint.contains_expressions:
            fields.extend(constraint.fields)
        else:
            for expression in constraint.expressions:
                # deconstruct() returns (path, fields, kwargs)
                _, (field, ), _ = expression.deconstruct()
                fields.append(field)
    return fields
```